# Redirecting domain to a folder

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, configuration, hosting

I have a domain www.mydomain.com. It is hosted on Apache.

When I hit this domain, it takes me to the Apache default page.

Now my domain works as follows:

```
www.domain.com/support
www.domain.com/support/admin
www.domain.com/support/staff
www.domain.com/support/support
```

I want it to be

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/admin
www.domain.com/staff
www.domain.com/support
```

Support is the name of my application hosted in Apache.

Here are my vhost entries:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/www.domain.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/www.domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

What should I edit? How shall I do this? Should I remove the '/support/' thing from my link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move everything up a directory?

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/www.domain.com/support
mv * ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache's mod_rewrite

I use lighttpd ather than Apache, so this might not be exactly right, but something like...

```
<Directory /support>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
</Directory>
```